# Would a Little Endian vs Big Endian data structure change my answer?

Tags: c, pointers, endianness

I’m presented with the following problem:

```
int i[20] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}; 
int *p;
```

with i[0]starting at address 1,242 on a Big Endian machine with 32-bit integers.

What does p equal after the following statement?

```
p = &i[2] + 4;
i[0] = *(p + 5) - 8;
```

Result:

```
p = 1242 + 4 * (2 + 4) = 1,266
i[0] = i[(6 + 5)] – 8 = 3
```

If this was on a Little E machine, would my solution change?

Comment: well, make up some memory addresses, and run the code "Manually"...

Comment: I think there is no change, the compiler takes care of this things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does p equal after the following statement?

`p` will have same value. You are just assigning it some addresses - e.g. here: `p = &i[2] + 4`, this is not related with endianness.

*If you run this whole code on same machine*, neither will value of `i[0]` change; because you are operating on "whole" integers, not reading say 1st byte of a 4 byte integer using `char` pointer.

e.g. if you had

```
int x = 1;
unsigned char * y = (unsigned char*) &x;
```

Then `*y` would equal 1 on little endian machine, and 0 on big endian.

---

Also there is a little bit different story if client sends this array to another machine then it all depends how client serializes (e.g. which endianness) it and how server interprets it. Then endianess issues might come into play (e.g. because client and server might have different endianness).

Here is [more](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/) reading for you to understand this concept.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as correct when the time expires.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing the representation of an int using a char*? If not then endianness doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

You make a huge mental mistake by writing down an address as an integer. DON"T DO THAT!

&i [2] is the address of i [2].
If you add 4 you get the address of i [6].
p + 5 gives the address of i [11], and *(p+5) is the number stored in i [11].

Nothing whatsoever with endianness.

Comment: but endianness comes into play if that integer array is sent over network and read as OP suggest, please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

No.  Little Endian vs Big Endian only matters if you are using different types.  As long as you're only working with ints, the differences are abstracted away.

`i` is an integer array, so it refers to a collection of int-aligned memory addresses, interpreted according to the endianness of the system.

`p` is an integer pointer, so it can only refer to int-aligned memory addresses, interpreted according to the endianness of the system.

If you were using a `char *` or `void *` somewhere in your code, endianness could matter.

Answer (score 0):

Endianess only matters when you access the *individual bytes* of any integer type with size 2 bytes or larger.

Your code doesn't do this, so it does not depend on endianess.

And that's all.